# Recoding years to year nr. 0,1,2 ect

Tags: r, numeric, recode

I'm not very good in English or in R but hopefully I can manage to explain the problem

I have a dataset where there is one column with years, from 1952 to 2007. I want to recode and reorganize it so that the first year is number 0, the next year nr. 1 and so on...

Can anyone help me?

I have tried recode(), arrange (),

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean like this? :

```r
df <- data.frame(years = 1952:2007)
is.na(df$years[sample(1:nrow(df), size = 10)]) <- TRUE

head(df)
#>   years
#> 1    NA
#> 2  1953
#> 3  1954
#> 4  1955
#> 5  1956
#> 6  1957

df$years_recoded <- df$years - min(df$years, na.rm = T)
head(df)
#>   years years_recoded
#> 1    NA            NA
#> 2  1953             0
#> 3  1954             1
#> 4  1955             2
#> 5  1956             3
#> 6  1957             4
```

<sup>Created on 2022-12-03 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: You may need `min(df$years, na.rm=TRUE)` to protect against missing data in your years column.

Comment: @Spacedman, indeed. Updated. Though this raises another question ( for OP )- do recoded values have a certain contextual meaning or not, i.e should `0`represent the smallest value or  `1952`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want this: To start with 0 we have to substract 1 from `row_number()`

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(year_recoded = row_number()-1) %>% 
  head()
```

```
  years year_recoded
1  1952            0
2  1953            1
3  1954            2
4  1955            3
5  1956            4
6  1957            5
```